# jQuery: how to combine two events: $(document).ready + $("#superid a").hover?

Tags: jquery, events

My problem is simple. I can't figure out how to combine two events, that perform the same function.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
//do something
});
```

+

```
$("#superid a").hover(function()
{
//do something the same
});
```

How to combine it?

Answer (score 5):

If I well understood

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var yourfunction = function() {
      // do something
   }


   $("#superid a").hover(function() {
      yourfunction();
   });

   yourfunction();
});
```

Comment: your hover function is inside document ready so you dont need to call that function again, useless.

Comment: @barlasapaydin then how would you execute a function both at domready and at hover event? I think your downvote is wrong...

Comment: @barlasapaydin It is correct this way. (Though you don't need the function in domready)

Comment: @barlasapaydin - you are wrong, and this is the right way to do it. Correctly encapsulates the `yourfunction` method inside the document ready, calls it, and wires up the `hover` correctly.

Comment: Please, who downvoted could explain how can I improve my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new function and pass it as a callback to both events.

```
function myAction() { ... }
$(document).ready( myAction );
$( ... ).hover( myAction );
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the `hover` event is usually wired up *inside* the `document.ready`!

Comment: You don't always have to, the dom can be ready depending on where you include the script. If its absolutely necessary to wait, @F. Calderan's answer is the way to do it.